# cronjobs cakephp using shell, need help

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

i am creating a shell in cakephp to print a data from a model, following this tutorial about [Creating Shells & Tasks](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1107/Creating-Shells-Tasks)

```
class ReportShell extends Shell {
    var $uses = array('Report');
    function main() {
        $reports = $this->Report->findAll();
        foreach($reports as $report) {
            $this->out('Report Name: ' . $report['Report']['name'] . "\n");
        }

        $this->out("Total Reports: " . count($reports) . "\n"); 
    }
}
```

but then when i typed `$cake report` on the console, i get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Unable to load DataSource file dbo\dbo_mysql_ex.php in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\cake_test\core\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on line 178
```

any idea how should i fix this?

UPDATE:
following @olezhek suggestion, i have edited my database.php file and use "mysql" instead of "mysql_ex", i am indeed getting a different error message, which stated that i have an undefined function on a model that i didnt even load on my report shell, how is this possible ??

thanks

NOTE: i have build the database along with the table (reports), the fields and entries, and i am manage to view the table entries using the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're trying to use custom mysql driver (for example, for debugging queries). You should change the driver name to 'mysql' in your /app/config/database.php. Or, if you still want to trace queries, you should create the /app/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql_ex.php and put the code from here http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/32872 into it.

Answer (score 0):

should $this->Report->findAll(); not be $this->Report->find('all');?

side note: why would you want to run that in a cron, the echo will not do anything as nobody will see it

Comment: findAll() is just about the same with find("all"), well i want to try to make this work before i put the real cron thing, and since i will be using a lot of models in the real cron jobs, so i guess this represent enough